# Programmatically Pull From GitHub

Tags: ruby, git, github, wiki

I understand conceptually what I need to do, I'm primarily here to ask about what tools I need for the job.

I've set up and configured [Robut](https://github.com/justinweiss/robut) for use with HipChat so my team can, nominally, entertain themselves and also be able to access the contact info of other members (the important part).  Obviously I don't want the bot hosted locally every day, so I want to push it to a server; along the same vein, I also don't want to have to constantly update Robut's plugin for whois every time the team changes.

We have a Contact Information wiki set up on Github, so I'm wondering what ruby gems/etc. I might need in order to pull down the wiki page, at which point I will be able to parse it.

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand. Perhaps you can rephrase your question to be clear. I think you're saying you want a way to programmatically update a git repository, and reload some config from here. Have you considered just doing this with a cron job `cd dir && git pull origin master && touch tmp/restart.txt`?

Comment: Essentially what I'm going for is the ability to programmatically pull a file from a repo, and then my chatbot would be able to parse it as necessary.

Comment: might seem like a hack, but as a simple solution my suggested cronjob will probably work. Otherwise I'd look at using the github api, or `ruby-git`.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and report back - It's more of an after-hours fun thing to work on...for work...but if I get something working I'll let you know :-)

Answer (score 0):

Github's API doesn't have Wiki support. What you can do is contact support at Github and see what your options are.